# AMP Script Not Working on Google AMP Cache (ampproject.org)

Tags: vue.js, amp-html

We have a very strange problem.  Here's for starters.

1. AMP Page in Question: https://justbang.com/amp/ (valid + functions correctly upon clicking yellow button in hero section to show modal / signup process)
2. Google Cache of AMP Page: https://justbang-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/justbang.com/amp/index.html --> (valid BUT DOES NOT function correctly upon clicking yellow button in hero section to show modal / signup process - AMP script fails.

   3. Upon downloading the page source for https://justbang-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/justbang.com/amp/index.html and saving it + running it on local host, it functions 100% properly (clicking yellow button results in modal showing proper content).  We uploaded the same source on https://justbang-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/justbang.com/amp/index.html to the following file on our server https://justbang.com/amp/current-google-cache.html - which also functions correctly.

So for some reason this source in question:
1. executes properly on localhost
2. executes properly on our server
3. does not execute properly when hosted on ...amprpoject.org...

Any information is greatly appreciated.  **Thank you for your time.**